# How to get page no in tesseract while ocring multi tiff file

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

How can we get the page no in command line while ocring a multi tiff file. For eg -

```
tesseract myfile.tif output-page_no.txt
```

Here the output file should have the corresponding page no from the tiff file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hocr output option would produce page numbers. The text, however, can output page breaks, given the appropriate switches:

```
tesseract -c include_page_breaks=1 -c page_separator="[PAGE SEPRATOR]" 109359.tiff 109359
```

See this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/tesseract-dev/page$20break/tesseract-dev/VsgJ9R-cTQ0/OMeDjYWoAdQJ).